# How is the impl. of Rust's channels functionally different from Go's impl. of channels?

Tags: go, rust, channel

I specifically intend to use the channel functionality of either language in developing a scalable web service. I am unclear at present about which one would be easier to implement but also which one would better fit the intended design, help maintain uptime, require minimal overhead etc.
I understand that the Go implementation uses CSP methodology, though I'm unclear exactly what the Rust implementation is based on and whether it is even analogous to the Go version.

Is there any similarity or are they too different to compare to each other?
Are there use-cases where both implementations would operate mostly the same?

Comment: One of the implementations is written in Rust, and one is written in Go, which seems like a large difference.

Comment: Here is an article about it: https://gsquire.github.io/static/post/a-rusty-go-at-channels/

Comment: That article predates the creation of async channels, unfortunately.

Comment: I did add focus to the original question, it has been closed twice now.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no such thing as the Rust channel.**

Whereas in Go channels are a language concept provided by the Go run-time, in Rust channels can be implemented in a library, and therefore there are as many channels implementations as there are libraries, each with different goals and trade-offs:

- There is one MPSC (Multi-Producer, Single-Consumer) channel in the [standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html).
- There are MPMC (Multi-Producer, Multi-Consumer) channels in the [crossbeam ecosystem](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-channel) and in the [async-std crate](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/sync/fn.channel.html)<sup>1</sup>.

All of those implementations offer different interfaces, capabilities, and performance trade-offs.

<sup>1</sup> *Not an official crate, simply a port of `std` functionalities to `async`.*

Comment: And I will not recommend any particular implementation, given that library recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I should have mentioned that any implementation whether a crate or in the std library would be alright.

Comment: @warsong: But how is anyone but you supposed to choose which implementation to go with? As I mentioned, to start with, they offer different functionatilities -- what if the implementation selected is useless to you because it lacks a fundamental functionality that you cannot do without (or can only emulate at great cost)? I am afraid that only *you* can review the different implementations and pick one that suits your needs...

Comment: ... if you are unclear on which implementation to go with, then you'd need to first ask for advice, and SO is not good at that. You could get advice in the chatroom (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust), on URLO (users.rust-lang.org), or on reddit (r/rust).

Comment: I wasn't asking anyone to choose for me, I was asking what the actual differences are in the 2 implementations.

Comment: @warsong: To make the comparison, one has to choose a Rust implementation, and if the chosen Rust implementation does not fit your functional requirements, the whole answer is a waste of time. This is why it's necessary for you to find one (or several) implementations that will fit your functional requirements before asking for a comparison.